# Why is pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent sensitive to my working directory?

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a script that's two directories down.

```
❯ tree
.
└── foo
    └── bar
        └── test.py
❯ cd foo/bar
❯ cat test.py

    from pathlib import Path
    print(Path(__file__).parent)
    print(Path(__file__).parent.parent)
```

When I run it from the directory that contains it, PathLib thinks that the file's grandparent is the same as its parent.

```
❯ python test.py

    . # <-- same
    . # <-- directories
```

But when I run it from the top level, PathLib behaves correctly.

```
❯ cd ../..
❯ python foo/bar/test.py

    foo/bar # <-- different
    foo     # <-- directories
```

Am I misunderstanding something about PathLib's API, or is something else causing its output to be sensitive to my working directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call [`Path.resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) to make your path
absolute (a full path including all parent directories and removing all symlinks)

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path(__file__).resolve().parent)
print(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent)
```

This will cause the results to include the entire path to each directory, but the behaviour will work wherever it is called from

Comment: Does not work for network shared directories (e.g. "\\my_network_space\some_dir").  
Any ideas?